# Magento - PayPal Standard Payment not working

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.9

Since magento-1.9.??, standard payment & express checkout is combined I think.

But in my shop ([www.fiduciashop.de](https://www.fiduciashop.de)) only express is working ( I have only 1 PayPal option as customer).

[image]

In Backend looks like is standard paypal but in frontend the customer go through express checkout (cmd=_express...)

[image]

[image]

When PP redirects me :
[image]

---

How can I make PayPal standard working again? 
Or PayPal did this with some reason?

Comment: In the attached screens I think only one payment is enabled. And second reason can be the billing address.

Comment: There I dont have any possibility to choose between these 2 paypal mehtods. Its very annoying. I read about deactivate from database but it cause that´s not working anymore.

Comment: PayPal is standard is now PayPal Express Checkout with magento. The naming conventions are confusing as there is essential NO difference between standard and express checkout in this setup; why they say [includes] as it is. You can see with the TOKEN=EC-XXXX where EC means Express Checkout

Comment: @GeekNinja , thanks for that information - however its like express checkout cause just paypal redirect me after selected paymentmethod, all other giving me possibility to review order

Comment: That is correct. That is what I mentioned. This is PayPal Express Checkout. Go int your stores configuration scope and see how PayPal is setup there. It may be that you have it removed from Default settings